# 7 passengers enter the train with 4 carriages numbered 1 to 4.

Tags: probability, statistics

7 passengers enter the train with 4 carriages numbered 1 to 4. Each passengers chooses
at random a carriage to go into, independently of other passengers.

a) Compute the probability that in one of the carriages there are 4 passengers and that
there is exactly 1 passenger in each of the remaining three carriages.

b) Compute the probability that there is at least one passenger in each carriage.

My rough workings:
a) P(one of the carriages has four passengers and exactly 1 passenger in the remaining 3 carriages) = ((7C4)*4!)/4^7

Comment: Could you edit into your question any thoughts you have had yourself so far?

Comment: So where are you stuck?

Comment: @MathLover in part a) i am not sure how to combine the two probabilities and part b) dont know where to start

Comment: I do not understand your working for the first part. In total there are $4^7$ arrangements and now in how many ways can you place $4$ passengers in a carriage?

Comment: @MathLover 4choose1? therefore 4/4^7?

Comment: why ${4 \choose 1}$? There are $7$ passengers. Choose $4$ passengers.

Comment: @MathLover 7choose4 out of 4^7?

Comment: Think what else you need to do now that you have chosen $4$ passengers out of $7$ and $3$ passengers who are going to be in different carriages.

Comment: Does this answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4053945

Comment: @MathLover would you multiply by 3!?

Comment: You will multiply by $4!$ as now you need to arrange these groups into $4$ carriages

Comment: @MathLover wouldn't you multiply by 3! since there would be 3 carriages left? sorry im dont quite understand

Comment: But you have not chosen carriage for $4$ passengers yet. There are $4$ ways right? So $4 \cdot 3!$ - same thing?

Comment: @MathLover i see now thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

For $(b)$, please apply Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion which is there in the other answer that user mentioned in comments. In this case as the numbers are small, you can also simply count as below -

As each carriage must have at least one passenger, possibilities are permutations of $\{4 \ 1 \ 1 \ 1\}, \{3 \ 2 \ 1 \ 1\}, \{2 \ 2 \ 2 \ 1\}$

$\displaystyle {7 \choose 4} \cdot 4! + {7 \choose 3}  {4 \choose 2} \cdot 4! + {7 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1} \frac{6!}{2!2!2!} = 8400 \ $ favorable arrangements.

Explanation: First term is what we discussed for $(a)$ in comments. Second term is where we choose $3$ and $2$ passengers out of $7$and then arrange them in carriages. Last term is where we choose $1$ passenger out of $7$ first and place in one of the carriages. Then rest $6$ passengers can be arranged in rest $3$ carriages.

Now divide it by $\displaystyle 4^7$ which is total number of arrangements.