# Probability of at least one person in a car

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 7 people, and 4 cars (the cars have no limit to how many people they can fit). Each person randomly chooses a car, and their decision is independent of what the others choose.
I need to find the probability that there is at least one person in each car.

I'm thinking to do 1 - probability there is at least 1 car with 0 people in, but I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: You have to extend your thinking a bit. Read up on inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Variants of this question have been turning up a lot lately.

Comment: Have you studied Inclusion-Exclusion yet?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about inclusion exclusion haha. I've used that just now and ended up with 525/1024. Would you be able to confirm that this is correct for me?

Comment: yes that is correct answer

Comment: You are getting votes to 'close' this question, possibly based on not showing what you tried. Please edit your (correct, +1) solution from inclusion-exclusion method into your Question.

Comment: @BruceET The context doesn't have to be a solution attempt. There are many ways one can show context such as the ways listed in 'how to ask a good question'.

Answer (score 1):

There are in total $4^7$ ways 7 person can choose a car. From this number we shall subtract the cases where one car is empty, which is $\binom 41 3^7$. In doing so we however multiply subtract the cases with two or more empty cars and shouls correct this. This is the inclusion-exclusion principle so that the number of cases with no car empty is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^4(-1)^i\binom4i(4-i)^7=4!{7\brace4}.
$$
Thus the number reported in the comment is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at simulation. With a million
embarkations of the cars, one can expect about
two or three places of accuracy. The simulated
answer is in good agreement with $525/1024.$
(+1) for @User's Answer.

```
set.seed(2021)
m = 10^6;  event = logical(m)
for(i in 1:m){
 c = sample(1:4,7,rep=T)
 t[i] = c(tabulate(c),0,0,0)[1:4]
 event[i] = (sum(t >= c(1,1,1,1))==4) 
}
mean(event)
[1] 0.513738
525/1024
[1] 0.5126953
```

Illustration of R code in terms of the last iteration.
Cars are numbered 1 through 4. Modification to 'tabulate' is needed in case
higher numbered cars happen to be empty.
Vector `event` consists of 1 million `TRUE`s and
`FALSE`s; its `mean` is the proportion of its
`TRUE`s.

```
c
[1] 2 1 3 2 2 2 2  # cars chosen by 11 passengers
t
[1] 1 5 1 0        # numbers in each car, 1 - 4
event[10^6]
[1] FALSE          # event FALSE (last car empty)
```